# Convert chapters from xml to ffmetadata?

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line-interface, metadata, video-encoding

I wanted to add chapters to my encoded mkvs, but I get `*.xml` files when I download it from online. So is there any way to convert it to `FFMETADATAFILE` so that when I encode it using ffmpeg I can add chapters to my mkv??

**Sample Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- <!DOCTYPE Chapters SYSTEM "matroskachapters.dtd"> -->

-<Chapters>


-<EditionEntry>

<EditionFlagDefault>1</EditionFlagDefault>

<EditionFlagHidden>0</EditionFlagHidden>


-<ChapterAtom>

<ChapterUID>95534594</ChapterUID>

<ChapterTimeStart>00:00:00.000000000</ChapterTimeStart>

<ChapterTimeEnd>00:01:30.000000000</ChapterTimeEnd>

<ChapterFlagHidden>0</ChapterFlagHidden>

<ChapterFlagEnabled>1</ChapterFlagEnabled>


-<ChapterDisplay>

<ChapterString>Chapter 1</ChapterString>

<ChapterLanguage>und</ChapterLanguage>

</ChapterDisplay>

</ChapterAtom>



</EditionEntry>

</Chapters>
```

**Sample Output**

```
;FFMETADATA1
title=bike\\shed
;this is a comment
artist=FFmpeg troll team

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=0
#chapter ends at 0:01:00
END=60000
title=chapter \#1
[STREAM]
title=multi\
line
```

*By the way I use ffmpeg in cli mode only.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, i wrote this handy dandy script that does exactly that.
link to [gist](https://gist.github.com/ArjixGamer/c0226796b67b2015fa8fa68a8c91f665)

### Script

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # pip install bs4
import re


with open(r"PATH/TO/CHAPTERS/XML/FILE.xml", 'r') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'html.parser')


chapters = soup.select('editionentry > chapteratom')
chapters_array = []


for chapter in chapters:
    time = re.search(r'(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})', str(chapter))
    hrs = int(time.group(1))
    mins = int(time.group(2))
    secs = int(time.group(3))

    minutes = (hrs * 60) + mins
    seconds = secs + (minutes * 60)
    timestamp = (seconds * 1000)
    chap = {
        "title": re.sub(r'(=|;|#|\n)', r'\\\1', chapter.find('chapterstring').text),
        "startTime": timestamp
    }
    chapters_array.append(chap)

text = ";FFMETADATA1\n\n"

for i in range(len(chapters_array)-1):
    chap = chapters_array[i]
    title = chap['title']
    start = chap['startTime']
    end = chapters_array[i+1]['startTime']-1
    text += f"\n[CHAPTER]\nTIMEBASE=1/1000\nSTART={start}\nEND={end}\ntitle={title}\n"

text = text.strip()

print(text)
```

### How to use?

Replace the `PATH/TO/CHAPTERS/XML/FILE.xml` with the actual filepath of the xml file.

Make sure you have python 3 installed.

Run `python -m pip install bs4` to install a dependency.

And just run the script. (eg `python script.py` where script.py is the name you used to save the script)

If you appreciate my answer then please mark it as the accepted answer for this question.

PS: this script was inspired from https://ikyle.me/blog/2020/add-mp4-chapters-ffmpeg